# Modify automated stored procedure date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this SQL Server stored procedure. This procedure gets executed every day by a SQL Server agent job grabbing documents based on the date parameters below.

```
    AND DRDateCaptured between '2015-04-15 00:00:01.000' and Getdate()
    AND DRDocumentFileName <> isnull(OriginalDocName,'')
```

I have to modify the query so it grabs two more days each time its executed so for example if the job is executed tomorrow it would grab 4/12/15 through today, the next day would be 4/10/15 and so forth. I was looking up different ways to do this and was thinking about using `DATEDIFF` but as I am new to sql I am not sure how to implement it. Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Edit: another part of the procedure I'm not sure if this helps at all:

```
 PartList = dbo.fn_GetClientParts(D.DID, D.DClientDocNumber),
    convert(VARCHAR, d.dbek, 101) AS bekstart,
    convert(VARCHAR, d.dbekendd, 101) AS bekend
    Empty = '||',
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), GetDate(), 101) AS DATE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me suggest you implement an auxiliary date table from which you can do calculations. This will boost your performance.

Second, you need to do a combination of DATEDIFF and DATEADD if you have a set date that you want to base the date from.

In your example you said you wanted to expand the date range by 2 for each date beyond a certain date. In your example, July 31st is the pivital date.

The distance between end points from your pivital point is 3x where x is the number of days from July 31st to today's date.

```
SELECT
  GETDATE() AS today,
  DATEDIFF( DD, '7/31/2015', GETDATE() ) AS days_from_pivot,
  DATEADD( DD, -3 * DATEDIFF( DD, '7/31/2015', GETDATE() ), GETDATE() ) AS past_target_date
```

Your condition would then be:

```
DRDateCaptured BETWEEN DATEADD( DD, -3 * DATEDIFF( DD, '7/31/2015', GETDATE() ), GETDATE() ) AND GETDATE()
```

If you want to strip out the time in the first date, you can use the following:

```
DRDateCaptured BETWEEN CONVERT( DATETIME, FLOOR( CONVERT( FLOAT, DATEADD( DAY, -3 * DATEDIFF( DD, '7/31/2015', GETDATE() ), GETDATE() ) ) ) ) AND GETDATE()
```

---

If you'd like to see how this works across 100 days from the pivot date you can run the following query:

```
DECLARE @pivot_date DATETIME
SELECT @pivot_date = CONVERT( DATETIME, '7/31/2015' )

SELECT
  CONVERT( DATETIME, FLOOR( CONVERT( FLOAT, DATEADD( DAY, -3 * DATEDIFF( DD, @pivot_date, target_end_date ), target_end_date ) ) ) ) AS start_date,
  target_end_date AS end_date
FROM
  (  
    SELECT
      DATEADD( DAY, iq_a.n * 10 + iq_b.n, @pivot_date ) AS target_end_date
    FROM
      ( SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 AS n UNION SELECT 3 AS n UNION SELECT 4 AS n UNION SELECT 5 AS n UNION SELECT 6 AS n UNION SELECT 7 AS n UNION SELECT 8 AS n UNION SELECT 9 AS n UNION SELECT 0 AS n ) AS iq_a,
      ( SELECT 1 AS n UNION SELECT 2 AS n UNION SELECT 3 AS n UNION SELECT 4 AS n UNION SELECT 5 AS n UNION SELECT 6 AS n UNION SELECT 7 AS n UNION SELECT 8 AS n UNION SELECT 9 AS n UNION SELECT 0 AS n ) AS iq_b
  ) AS virtual_auxiliary_date_table
ORDER BY
  target_end_date
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you sooo much for this response much appreciated! I am little confused as to why the pivotal date is july 31? The reason I had to modify this query is that although this job was meant to start on that date specified in the question and everyday it is being executed, I have to have it go as far back as sept 1, would I replace the july date with sept then?

Comment: When recalculating from your example, it came up as August 1st, not July 31st. Here's the calculation: SELECT DATEADD( DAY, -1 * ( DATEDIFF( DAY, '2015-04-12', '2015-09-25' ) / 3 ), '2015-09-25' ). From that date, every day you move ahead for the end date, you move back two days for the start date. I placed the pivot date in a variable so you could easily change that date to your needs. Whatever that central point is.

Comment: oh I see so say for example the date is "2015-03-19' instead of '2015-04-15' using your calculation the pivotal date would be '2015-07-24', I apologize but can you explain what the significance of this date this? using your example I see how the end date increases by a day and goes back 2 days it works very well but I dont understand the significance of the pivotal date's use in the query. Again thank you so much for your help I truly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like DATEADD

```
2 is the days to add..  -2 would give 2 days prior. then use getdate() or the date parameter you need as the last parameter supplied.

select DATEADD(day, 2, getdate())
```

Comment: Thank you for replying! so I would put SELECT DATEADD(day, 2,getdate()) instead of the Getdate() so it would like this?                                                                                                                                                                                                                   AND DRDateCaptured between '2015-03-19 00:00:01.000' and Select DATEADD(day, 2,getdate())
AND DRDocumentFileName <> isnull(OriginalDocName,'')

Comment: Adding 2 will push you two days into the future. From your description you're wanting to move two days back for every one day you move forward.

Comment: @paurian ah yes I meant -2 but I wasnt sure where to place this select statement in the procedure